# Regex for Maching Floor Input Such As E, D, U1, U2 ect

Tags: regex, typescript

I've been fiddling around yesterday but coulnd't get a proper solution. I'm trying to get a regex which maches with floor Inputs (for a building) with all upper case letters.

I want to match either only `E`, only `D`, only `1, 2, 3 ect.` or only `U1, U2, U3 ect.`, the last one also must be in the correct order the letter comes before the number, not the other way around.

So far I've come up with this regex here: `/[UED]|[1-9]/g`

But this matches way too many things, for example `2U` would also match or `ED22` or `UD1` and so on. I was trying it out with `regexr.com` but had no success so far to solve this problem.

Has anyone an idea how I can mach specifically only one of the four above mentionned inputs?

```
Valid Inputs:
E
U8
D
32
etc..

Invalid Inputs:
2U
ED
EEE
D1
etc.
```

Comment: `^[DE]|(?:U[1-9][1-9]*)$` either `E` or `D` or `U+positive number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[ED]|U?[1-9]\d*)$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kdU74T/4)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching either of

  - `[ED]` - an `E` or `D`
  - `|` - or
  - `U?[1-9]\d*` - an optional `U`, a non-zero digit and any 0+ digits
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @Miger [Your `^[DE]|(?:U[1-9][1-9]*|[1-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/Wmw5ye/1) allows a number after `U`. Mine does not.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry. Your answer is ok but still not exactly what I need because it doesn't match numbers by themselves, this is how it should be: `^(?:[ED]|U[1-9]|[1-9]\d*)$`

Comment: @Miger Use `^(?:[ED]|U?[1-9]\d*)$` then. I understand `123` should also match.

Comment: That looks neat, thanks alot for your help and also the explanation above, very nice :)